# Split string in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm still new in Clojure; I'm trying to split the values parsed from CSV file but without using `clojure.string/split` lib or any other lib just `clojure.core`, please some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `clojure.string` is part of the "core" library - there are no external dependencies needed to use it. Why not use it? If this is an exercise, please show us what you have tried.

Comment: mind to share, why?  is this homework?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can accomplish the same result with re-seq and string/split

```
user> (clojure.string/split "a,b,c,d,e" #",")
["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"]

user> (re-seq #"[^,]+" "a,b,c,d,e")
("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")
```

Both of these are available with no dependencies so there is little reason not to use string/split in many cases.

parsing CSV is also a good choice if you are willing to add a dependency:

```
user> (require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv])
nil
user> (csv/read-csv "A,B,C\n1,2,3\n4,5,5")
(["A" "B" "C"] ["1" "2" "3"] ["4" "5" "5"])
```

Comment: `(re-seq #"[^,]" "abc,d") ;; => ("a" "b" "c" "d")` - I think OP wants `#"[^,]+"`

Comment: clojure.data.csv isn't built in. You need to add it as a dependency.

Comment: oops, thats clojure.data.json/read-str not csv thats in by default. I'll take that last bit out of the answer. thanks for checking up

Answer (score 3):

If your hands were tied and couldn't use `clojure.string` or `clojure.data.csv` or `re-seq` or interop:

```
(defn comma-separate [s]
  (->> s
      (partition-by #{\,})
      (take-nth 2)
      (map #(apply str %))))

(comma-separate "foo,bar") ;; ("foo" "bar")
```

I agree that you should use `clojure.string` or `clojure.data.csv`